# Python input normalized value and return color

Tags: python, color-mapping

I am trying to create a function that will take a normalized value between 0 and 1 and return a color value between red and blue (rainbow colormap). see createlink

```
    def normPoint(self,level):
        return .02222*level+2.4444
    def createLink (self, output_level):
        cdict = {'red': ((0., 1, 1),
                 (0.05, 1, 1),
                 (0.11, 0, 0),
                 (0.66, 1, 1),
                 (0.89, 1, 1),
                 (1, 0.5, 0.5)),
         'green': ((0., 1, 1),
                   (0.05, 1, 1),
                   (0.11, 0, 0),
                   (0.375, 1, 1),
                   (0.64, 1, 1),
                   (0.91, 0, 0),
                   (1, 0, 0)),
         'blue': ((0., 1, 1),
                  (0.05, 1, 1),
                  (0.11, 1, 1),
                  (0.34, 1, 1),
                  (0.65, 0, 0),
                  (1, 0, 0))}
        cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('color_map', cdict,256)
        color_value = self.normPoint(output_level)
        color = self.get_color_name(cmap(color_value))
        print color, color_value
    def closest_color(self,requested_color):
        min_colors = {} 
        for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
            r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
            rd = (r_c - requested_color[0]) ** 2
            gd = (g_c - requested_color[1]) ** 2
            bd = (b_c - requested_color[2]) ** 2
            min_colors[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
        return min_colors[min(min_colors.keys())]
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: So you want a value of zero (0.00) to result in Red, FF0000, (255,0,0), or wavelength 700nm, and one (1.00) to result in Blue, 0000FF, (0, 0, 255) or wavelength 450nm?  For 1.00 I'd actually opt for Violet, at wavelength 400nm.  If you use the spectral scale you'll miss the colors that are a mixture of colors, e.g. brown, or colors where all three RGB values are non-zero.

Comment: The problem is I can't seem to return any color other then black. Possibly somthing wrong with my color dict, but it was copied from the python documentation.

Comment: Also, I am using the webcolors and matplotlib libraries.